# how to run distinct SELECT query inside laravel blade file inside of a foreach loop?

Tags: sql, laravel, select, distinct, laravel-blade

i have two tables

`women-dress`

`women-dress_attributes`

`women-dress` has `price` , `color` and `women-dress_attributes` has `display_name` , `attribute_name` and `filter`

`filter` is a simple Y or N value
a row in `women-dress_attributes` looks like

```
Price  price  Y
```

since price has a filter value of Y i need to load distinct `price` values from `women-dress`
a part of my controller looks like this

```
 $Filter_query = DB::table($attribute_table_name)
                ->select('display_name','attribute')
                ->where('filter', '=', 'Y')
                ->get();
```

and inside my blade file i have

```
@foreach($Filter_query as $agm)
        <h4>{{ $agm->display_name }}</h4>

@endforeach
```

now how can i run another sql select distinct query to load the corresponding value inside the blade file?

or is there any better practice?

Comment: Try to look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins

Comment: something like this will work for you $Filter_query = DB::table('women-dress')
                ->join('women-dress_attributes','women-dress_attributes.women-dress_id','=','women-dress.id')
                ->distinct('women-dress.price')
                ->where('women-dress_attributes.filter', '=', 'Y')
                ->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this in laravel is to create a model for each of your 2 tables, and create  a relationship fucntion (i.e.`dress()`) between them.

Then you will be able to call in your blade this  `$agm->dress()->price` to get the price.

Read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) for creating models

And [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) for creating relationships between your models